# Is the second comma ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Usually, we see the following sentence:

> Hello Eric, could you please tell me why you are here?

But I am wondering if this one is ok too:

> Hello, Eric, could you please tell me why you are here?

Why is it ungrammatical or grammatical? Could you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* a pause in [direct address](http://thewritingresource.net/2010/02/11/punctuation-points-the-direct-address-comma/), so, `Hello, Eric,` is correct. The example from this reference makes this quite clear:

"Let's eat, grandpa," is not the same as "Let's eat grandpa." [Sorry if that's in bad taste.]

Comment: A noun used in direct address should be set off by commas as a structural matter, whether it spoken with a pause or not. It often is, but the pause is not what requires the comma.

Comment: The comma before Eric is not needed, but it does represent an additional pause, which might indicate that Eric didn't respond immediately to the 'hello'.